# wicket persistent object between panels

Tags: list, save, wicket, persistent

In wicket without saving to the session how can i have a persistent object for example a list which can be set in one panel and accessed from another. Iv done a lot of googleing and im not entirely sure how this would work. Any help would be appreciated greatly! Thank you.

Comment: "without saving to the session"? Will the list be accessed from the two places within the same request cycle?

Comment: the flow of logic would be one panel creates a  list which is then read by another panel and populated into a drop down box.

Comment: @Matthew I would probably let some kind of model instance create and hold the (`IModel` of) the `List`. Then each panel references the model instance for the `List` (or `IModel<List>`). I.e., no panel handles the data, they just hold a reference to some shared model instance.

Comment: @jensgram Thank you for the reply that has really helped me. Could you explain your concept slightly deeper as i understand the theory but the practical side i'm not sure where to start. Thanks

Comment: @jensgram Hi again, i have 1 class which adds the panels, could i create a model here and then pass this reference to both classes enabling them to both modify the same list? Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew I have tried to provide an example. In this, your class which adds the panels will hold a reference to the date model instance which in turn fetches and provides the `List` (`IModel<List>`) of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to the comments above, I will try and explain what I was thinking.

*Disclaimer*: It's been more than a year since I worked with Wicket, so the following should be read as an overall proof-of-concept. I cannot guarantee that it will compile (actually, I can almost certainly guarantee that it will not.)

```java
public class MyPage extends ... {
    ...
    MyPageModel pm = new MyPageModel();
    add(new MyPanel1(pm));
    add(new MyPanel2(pm));
    ...
}

public class MyPageModel implements Serializable {
    private IModel<List<MyDataObject>> dataObjects;

    public MyPageModel() {
        this.dataObjects = // Load list from somewhere
    }

    public IModel<List<MyDataObject>> getDataObjects() {
        return this.dataObjects;
    }
}

public class MyPanel1 extends ... {
    private MyPageModel pageModel;

    public MyPanel1(MyPageModel pageModel) {
        this.pageModel = pageModel;
        ...
        add(new ListSomethingComponent<MyDataObject>(pageModel.getDataObjects)); // Some list renderer component which takes a IModel<List<MyDataObject>> as data
    }
}

public class MyPanel2 extends ... {
    private MyPageModel pageModel;

    public MyPanel2(MyPageModel pageModel) {
        // Same as MyPanel1...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much it really. If the components that have to share their data work closely together (in the same or in subsequent requests), a shared model is the solution. If this isn't the case, use a session variable.