# Update wicket Panel using dialog modal

Tags: java, wicket

I have a panel that should be updated using data from a dialog Modul. In the Panels constructor, I have a datamodel which should populate components in the panel.

The Panel constructor looks like this:

```
      public MyPanel(String id, final MyDataMOdel aDataModel) {
    super(id);
            ....
          }
```

The panel is added in my page as:

```
       MyDataModel myDataModel = new MyDataModel();
    MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel("myPanel", myDataModel);
```

In the Open Dialog  `setWindowClosedCallback` method, I have my updated DataModel

```
            myModal.setWindowClosedCallback(new ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback()
            {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -1746088901018629567L;

                public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target)
                {
                    update myDataModel here
                    Got the updated datamodel here (I can see that it is updated)
                      target.add(myPanel)
                 ....
```

This way, I can't see the components in the panel got updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure what your `MyDataModel()` is. But you can use shared wicket Models.

```
          Model<YourDataObjectToShare> dataObjectToSHare = new Model<YourDataObjectToShare>()
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6394439155356911110L;

        @Override
        public YourDataObjectToShare getObject()
        {
            return ... The Updated Shared data here
        }
    };
```

Then Pass `dataObjectToSHare` to the panels argument

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532178/wicket-persistent-object-between-panels)

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I solved as follows:

```
    remove(myPanel);
    myPanel = new MyPanel("myPanel", myUpdatedDataModel);
    myPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(myPanel);
    target.appendJavaScript("window.location.reload()");
```